# How to convert VBA into Javascript in order to upload Excel Macro-enable workbook on Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-drive-api, vba

I would like to upload an Excel Macro-enable workbook on Google Drive but Google didn't support this file. They suggest me that I should convert VBA into Javascript and use Script Editỏ. I would like to convert this functionality in javascript, but I don't know where it is wrong. Can you give me a help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
      With Target(1, 2)
         .Value = Date
         .EntireColumn.AutoFit
      End With
   End If
End Sub
```

Javascript conversion attempt:

[image: converted code]

Comment: It will be more helpful if you paste your attempt at converting to JS in the question body

Comment: Please add code as _text_, not image

Comment: "where it's wrong" - hm I'm not sure what to say because _everything_ is wrong, that isn't even Javascript and it isn't using the Google Sheets API either...

Comment: And `Range("Test Message")` also doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to rewrite all the code, look for [GSpread.NET](http://scand.com/products/gspread/index.html). VBA and GSpread.NET work with Google Spreadsheets by using API from Microsoft Excel.
Need replace CreateObject(Excel.Application) to

Set objExcel = CreateObject("GSpreadCOM.Application")

app.MailLogon(Name, ClientIdAndSecret, ScriptId);

and work with Google Spreadsheets as normal Microsoft Excel documents.